# VPN and mobile proxy together

Tags: vpn, proxy

I want to use proxy mobile from my laptop, but I've read that it's not encrypted the data. So I thought about using VPN and proxy mobile together.
How do I "look" like in such case?
Will the data be encrypted and I will go out to the web with the proxy?
Thanks a lot

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVDQEoe6ZWY

Answer (score 1):

Practically all websites today use
[HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS).

For your purposes HTTPS is just as secure as VPN, since the
communication is encrypted and cannot be intercepted
(more exactly, can be intercepted but not understood).

You may use your computer for surfing with safety,
even when tethering with your phone.